Kubuntu 22.04 -> 24.04 fails while calculating the upgrade
When I attempt to upgrade my Kubuntu LTS distribution from 22.04 to 24.04 I get this error:
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

The package 'update-manager' is marked for removal but it is in the
removal deny list.

I tried removing the update-manager package manually and then re-running the release upgrade, but that also failed with this message:
Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

This was likely caused by:
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and
try the upgrade again.

I'm out of my depth now and can't work out how to find the offending PPA or determine if this is the issue in the first place.
Thanks so much for any help with this issue.

Did you remove all 3rd party programs and software sources?

Many users are reporting failed upgrades and broken installs. Please either fresh install 24.04, or wait for a few weeks before performing this upgrade.

For me it was because I was using a pipewire PPA. Seems to be a common issue. See this thread. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2500338
